# Single Responsibility Principle for many methods

Tags: oop, methods, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

How can you maintain single responsibility for a class that is  meant to perform multiple tasks? For example, if I want to write a code that represents a calculator that is able to add, subtract, multiply and perform a number of different calculations, how can I make the design of the software adhere to single responsibility?

Comment: Start with the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/single-responsibility-principle/info) to learn more about the SRP and note the link to Bob Martin's blog.

Answer (score 0):

The single responsibility principle can be applied on multiple levels. Method level, class level and even service level (thinking Microservices).

On method level a public  add() function applies to the SRP if there is only one thing it does, adding numbers. It should not be responsible for e.g. parsing an add command from a console command string or REST call or something else, this responsibility should be placed somewhere else.

The Calculator class has the responsibility to perform different kinds of calculations, here add, subtract, etc. But it shall not be responsible for, e.g., parsing commands or rendering results (such as creating html output for displaying).

And considering the service level an Ordering service should be responsible for everything concerning the processing of orders or providing information about orders. But it should not be responsible for warehousing of products and other stuff.

Note: a public method of class that internally uses private methods can still follow the SRP given the general task of the method adheres to one responsibility. For instance, the public divide() method might utilize a private method for checking and handling unwanted divisions by zero. This private method again adheres to the SRP as it only does one thing, handling division by zero but still fits into the bigger picture on the level above.

Comment: [What is the scope of the Single Responsibility Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893910/what-is-the-scope-of-the-single-responsibility-principle/57085753#57085753)