# How to apply Single Principle Responsibility in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I have a service that converts a xls file into html. It is working just fine, but it is quite a big method that doesn't follow any SOLID principles. Therefore I would like to improve it to follow at least the Single Responsibility Principle. But I really don't know how to apply it and find the level of abstraction in my case.

```
@Service
public class xlsToHtmlImpl implements MultipartFileToHtmlService {

private final HtmlLayout htmlLayout;

@Autowired
public xlsToHtmlImpl(HtmlLayout htmlLayout) {
    this.htmlLayout = htmlLayout;
}


@Override
public InputStream multipartFileToHtml(MultipartFile multipartFile, boolean hasOnlyOneSheet, boolean hasBorders) throws IOException {

    String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(multipartFile.getInputStream());

    Workbook workbook;
    assert fileName != null;
    //Selecting workbook depending on FileType
    if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(htmlLayout.FILE_TYPES[0])) {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    } else {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    }
    //Writing content of multipartFile to outputstream
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.openStyle());

    //Selecting style to apply depending on user input
    if (hasBorders) {
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.noBordersStyle());
    } else {
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.withBordersStyle());
    }
    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeStyle());

    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.openNewHtml());
    outputStream.write(fileName.getBytes());


    //Different algorithm for the content of the body depending on user input
    Sheet sheet;
    if (hasOnlyOneSheet) {
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rows.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newRow());
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cells.next();
                outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newCell());
                outputStream.write(cell.toString().getBytes());
                outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeCell());

            }
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeRow());
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i< workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newRow());
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeCell());
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeRow());
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rows.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
                outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
                outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newRow());
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cells.next();
                    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newCell());
                    outputStream.write(cell.toString().getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeCell());

                }
                outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeRow());
            }
        }
    }

    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeHtml());
    outputStream.close();

    //Returning result as ByteArrayInputStream to controller
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

Where `htmlLayout` contains html snippet like:

`public byte[] closeHtml() {return "</table></body></html>".getBytes();}`

I tried to follow this article: [https://www.baeldung.com/java-single-responsibility-principle#:~:text=As%20the%20name%20suggests%2C%20this,only%20one%20reason%20to%20change.&text=These%20classes%20are%20harder%20to%20maintain](https://www.baeldung.com/java-single-responsibility-principle#:%7E:text=As%20the%20name%20suggests%2C%20this,only%20one%20reason%20to%20change.&text=These%20classes%20are%20harder%20to%20maintain).

Following this article, I tried to create different classes as follow:

```
public class HtmlStyleWrapper {

private byte[] style;


public byte[] withBordersStyle() {
    return ("table, td{" +
            "    border: 1px solid black;\n" +
            "    border-collapse: collapse;\n" +
            "    padding: 9px;\n" +
            "}").getBytes();
}

public byte[] noBordersStyle() {
    return ("td {" +
            "    padding: 9px;\n" +
            "}").getBytes();
}

public byte[] openStyle() {
    return "</title></head><body><style>".getBytes();
}

public byte[] closeStyle() {
    return "</style><table>".getBytes();
}

public void wrapStyle(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, boolean hasBorders) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write(openStyle());
    if (hasBorders) {
        outputStream.write(noBordersStyle());
    } else {
        outputStream.write(withBordersStyle());
    }
    outputStream.write(closeStyle());
}


public class HtmlBodyWrapper {

private byte[] body;

public byte[] openNewHtml() {
    return "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>".getBytes();
}

public byte[] newLine() {
    return "\n".getBytes();
}

public byte[] closeHtml() {
    return "</table></body></html>".getBytes();
}

public byte[] newRow() {
    return "<tr>".getBytes();
}

public byte[] closeRow() {
    return "</tr>".getBytes();
}

public byte[] newCell() {
    return "<td>".getBytes();
}

public byte[] closeCell() {
    return "</td>".getBytes();
}

public void wrapBody(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, String fileName, boolean hasOnlyOneSheet, Workbook workbook) throws IOException {
//Write to outputstream
}
```

The aim would be to get something like

```
wrapHTMLBody(wrapStyle(htmlLayout.getHTML_STYLE()), table)
```

But I feel like I'm not taking the right approach and that I didn't understand correctly SRP.

Comment: I think this question is more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as the code works just fine.

Comment: @Amongalen I guess you're right, I'll transfer it there then

Answer (score 1):

> The single-responsibility principle (SRP) is a computer-programming principle that states that every class in a computer program should have responsibility over a single part of that program's functionality, which it should encapsulate. All of that module, class or function's services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility

This is from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)

In my opinion, the SRP is a kind of design thinking, which dependent on your cases and goals of your system to use it.

**In short, what public functions a class have to provide to its caller and those functions is enough to achieve the goals of the definition by this class.**

In your case, we should answer a question first:

**What feature or function does that class should provide to its caller?**

For example, it's just converting an Excel file to Html. The class `xlsToHtmlImpl` provides only one public function `multipartFileToHtml`, that is enough to achieve the goal.

The second question is that **Which options does the class support to set by caller?**

Maybe we need to define two classes:

- The class `HtmlStyleWrapper` define how to generate `Html Data` in memory.
- And the class `HtmlWritter` define how to output the `Html Data` to a file.

Anyway, SRP is that each classes just provides functions for it own responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, Single Responsibility simply means that you want to separate things that are independent and stick them in methods or classes.

This way, when you want to change an aspect of the algorithm, you can go to that method/class and change the behaviour there, without changing the rest of the code.
Also you could have 2 implementations of one aspect of the algorithm in 2 methods, and switch the behaviour by calling the appropriate method.

It makes for more modular, more testable, easier to debug code.

So for your example, let's first identify the responsibilities. I can see a few:

- Opening the workbook
- Writing the style block
- Writing the html block
- Closing the OutputStream

And with the "Writing the html block" responsibility, I can see nested responsibilities

- Open the HTML tag
- Write single sheet
- Write multi sheet
- Close the HTML tag

And in there, you can see that writing single sheet and multi sheet share some code, so that also can be extracted in a method.

So here is a way to write all this, nicely separated in methods:

```
public InputStream multipartFileToHtml(MultipartFile multipartFile, boolean hasOnlyOneSheet, boolean hasBorders) throws IOException {
    String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        Workbook workbook = createWorkbook(multipartFile);

        writeStyleBlock(outputStream, hasBorders);

        writeHtmlBlock(outputStream, workbook, fileName, hasOnlyOneSheet);
    } finally {
        outputStream.close();
    }

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());

}

private Workbook createWorkbook(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(multipartFile.getInputStream());
    String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    assert fileName != null;

    Workbook workbook;
    //Selecting workbook depending on FileType
    if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(htmlLayout.FILE_TYPES[0])) {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    } else {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    }

    return workbook;
}

private void writeStyleBlock(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, boolean hasBorders) {
    //Writing content of multipartFile to outputstream
    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.openStyle());

    //Selecting style to apply depending on user input
    if (hasBorders) {
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.noBordersStyle());
    } else {
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.withBordersStyle());
    }
    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeStyle());
}

private void writeHtmlBlock(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, Workbook workbook, String fileName, boolean hasOnlyOneSheet) throws IOException {
    openHtmlTag(outputStream, fileName);

    //Different algorithm for the content of the body depending on user input
    if (hasOnlyOneSheet) {
        writeSingleSheet(outputStream, workbook);
    } else {
        writeMultiSheet(outputStream, workbook);
    }

    closeHtmlTag(outputStream);
}

private void openHtmlTag(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, String fileName) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.openNewHtml());
    outputStream.write(fileName.getBytes());
}

private void closeHtmlTag(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream) {
    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeHtml());
}

private void writeSingleSheet(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, Workbook workbook) throws IOException {
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    writeRows(outputStream, sheet);
}

private void writeMultiSheet(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, Workbook workbook) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newRow());
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeCell());
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeRow());
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
        writeRows(outputStream, sheet);
    }
}

private void writeRows(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, Sheet sheet) throws IOException {
    Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rows.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newRow());
        while (cells.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cells.next();
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newCell());
            outputStream.write(cell.toString().getBytes());
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeCell());

        }
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeRow());
    }
}
```

You didn't even need new classes to separate responsibilities.
Now, if you want, you can further extract these methods into new classes, `WorkbookCreator`, `StyleBlockWriter`, `HTMLBlockWriter`, ...
Get to the granularity you want.

I think here, we don't need to get to classes, but if the HTML writer part became too big later on, it could be extracted into a new class

Comment: The SRP is different from "do only one thing." See: [What is the scope of the Single Responsibility Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57085753/1371329)

Comment: @jaco0646 Ok, I can remove the "do only one thing" bit. But the way I broke down the methods means that if somebody want to change how a single sheet is written, he will not be touching the method that writes the style block. This is what SRP is to me. Now, the separation could be done at different levels, methods, classes or modules.

Comment: @Bentaye Thank you, I'll keep digging the topic but your answer helped me understand a lot better.