# Single-responsibility principle: A question

Tags: oop

Does this imply that every Class must have only one Method/Function?

If I need to change this class, e.g. add a Property, and more than one of my Methods/Functions need to be changed to deal with this new Property, am I violating the principle of single responsibility?

Comment: Single responsibility means that each method should do one thing and do it well.  That's why in Java method names are usually a verb-noun combination.  A class has a single responsibility as well. but at a higher level.  An Item class, as one example, could have an item number field, item name field, item description field, item quantity field, and item price field.  Each field is a part of an item in an inventory.  Each getter / setter is responsible for one field.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, it is a common misconception that "do one thing" is equivalent to the SRP. In fact, they are two separate principles, each with its own [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57085753/1371329).